# is rgb values equals to cmyk percentage?

Tags: photoshop, rgb

is rgb numeric values equals to cmyk percentage?

for detail :

i have some rgb values for example r-212 g-231 b-211 and in Photoshop its showing cmyk as 40% 34% 80% 0%.i want to know can we get the same rgb values by giving cmyk percentage? because i have to use rgb in percentage in some particular application but i am not getting it with the help of photoshop...Please help in short tell me,
 is it possible to get rgb values in percentage with the help of photoshop?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://photo.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question isn't realy clear, but: no, rgb and cmyk are not the same, take a look at this picture to see the different color space they can represent (and, obviously, rgb consists of 3 values, cmyk consists of 4):

[image: rgb vs cmyk]

Comment: i mean to ask i have some rgb values for example r-212 g-231 b-211 and in Photoshop its showing cmyk as 40% 34% 80% 0%.i want to know can we get the same rgb values by giving cmyk percentage?  because i have to use rgb in percentage in some particular application but i am not getting it with the help of photoshop...Please help        in short tell me is it possible to get rgb values in percentage with the help of photoshop?

Comment: rbg is red, green and blue / cmyk is cyan, magenta and yellow and key(black) - thats obviously not the same. also, cmyk is a subtractive color model, rgb is additive - they are totally different. you can't calculate one from another as easy as you want (and, as you can see in my pictures, some colors can't be converted exactly). if you want to find a way to calculate from one to another, it takes only ten seconds to ask google (what you should do anyway before asking a question here)

Comment: i hope so, please see my edited comment. your question isn't real clear, maybe you should add some more information and an example to your question above (don't post it in a comment, so not everybody will see it)

Comment: Thanks oezi but  tell me if photoshop can do this, i searched in Google they said there is nothing like percentage values of RGB in Photoshop,so i just drop in here...

Answer (score 1):

**You can approximate a conversion between the [RGB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model) and [CMYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMYK_color_model) color spaces, but it's not going to be completely accurate or bidirectional.** There are numerous differences between the two color spaces that become relevant here, including their respective gamuts (see the diagram in oezi's answer), the additive vs. subtractive models, and the presence of black (key) in the CMYK space.

If you're merely interested in a simple way to convert a color from its RGB to CMYK representation, you can use the following code (arbitrarily in C#; feel free to convert to the language of your choice):

```
public CmykColor RgbToCmyk(int R, int G, int B)
{
    if ((R < 0) || (R > 255) || (G < 0) || (G > 255) || (B < 0) || (B > 255)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("RGB values must be in the range of 0 to 255");
    }

    if ((R == 0) && (G == 0) && (B == 0)) {
        return new CmykColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    } else {
        double calcR = 1 - (R / 255);
        double calcG = 1 - (G / 255);
        double calcB = 1 - (B / 255);

        double K = Math.Min(calcR, Math.Min(calcG, calcB));
        double C = (calcR - K) / (1 - K);
        double M = (calcG - K) / (1 - K);
        double Y = (calcB - K) / (1 - K);

        return new CmykColor(Convert.ToInt32(C), Convert.ToInt32(M), Convert.ToInt32(Y), Convert.ToInt32(K));
    }
}
```

But you'll have to decide if this simple approximation will produce results that are "close enough" for your needs. **The most important thing to realize is that a true conversion is entirely dependent upon the physical device/process and requires accurately calibrated color profiles for each of your devices (the monitor displaying the RGB, the printer printing the CMYK, and the substrate receiving the CMYK).**

This helps to explain why the above algorithm (or any other that you might implement on your own) is never going to match the results returned by Photoshop, which uses color profiles and some additional proprietary algorithms to handle its conversion. If this degree of accuracy is truly important, you could consider using something like the [Windows Color Management APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd372446%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to handle the conversion for you, which will automatically apply the current color profile, but you'll likely find that those results don't exactly match Photoshop's either.

**The bottom line is that color is subjective.** As I mentioned in the beginning, **even if you overcome the accuracy hurdle, you will still not have a conversion process that is bidirectional.** Even in Photoshop, you can't convert an image from RGB to CMYK and then back again without losing or altering some of the color information.

---

**EDIT:** You mention a couple of times in your comments that you just want "RGB values in percentage." I assume that this means *CMYK* percentages, but I suppose that it's worth pointing out if you just want to convert the standard 0-255 values for RGB components to an *RGB* percentage, you can just divide each value by 255 (the max), and then multiply by 100. So, for example:

> Red =          RGB(255, 0, 0) = 100% Red, 0% Green, 0% Blue
>
> DarkSeaGreen = RGB(143, 188, 143) = 56% Red, 74% Green, 56% Blue

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely. The [formula](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/xcmyk.aspx) is a little more complex than that, since CMYK has more components than RGB.